# val() function giving console error

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, numbers

The `input[type="number"]` has a `max` attribute, so people can't click higher than the number given. But this doesn't count for typed numbers, they can exceed far beyond the max number given. So, with jQuery, I want to make a solution for this. I already got this:

```
    var productPageInput = $('#product-options-wrapper .option input[type="number"].qty');
    var max = 60;
    productPageInput.attr('max', max);

    productPageInput.bind('keyup input', function(e){
        console.log($(this).val());
        if( $(this).val() > max ){
            $(this).val() = max;
        }
    });
```

But, everytime I execute this code, and I type above 60, this console error appears:

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment(…)
```

Which points to this line:

```
    $(this).val() = max;
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign a value:

```
$(this).val(max);
```

In general, a function call on the left-hand side of an assignment operator in JavaScript doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This ways posible with JQuery to set value of input

```
$("input").val("value");
//or
$("input")[0].value = "value";
```